# Jurisdiction in wrongful death lawsuits?

Tags: united-states, jurisdiction

In the case of a wrongful death lawsuit involving a manufactured part, where is the jurisdiction? Is it where the accident occurred or where the manufacturer is located.

For example, let's say an aircraft manufacturer is located in Georgia and a pilot flying one of the manufacturer's aircraft crashes and dies in Montana. The pilot's family claims the aircraft was manufactured in a negligent or defective way that contributed to the pilot's death and sues the manufacturer. Is the proper jurisdiction in Montana or Georgia?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it where the accident occurred or where the manufacturer is located?

Yes

> Is the proper jurisdiction in Montana or Georgia?

Both and possibly Federal jurisdiction applies  since it involves air transport.

Your mistaken assumption is that only one jurisdiction applies to any set of events - this is not true. Any jurisdiction can take an interest if their courts decide they can. For example, if the person who died resided in New South Wales, Australia then the NSW Coroners Court could decide they have jurisdiction. Similarly, if the part in question were made in China then China could claim jurisdiction. All of these claims of jurisdiction are valid and **non-exclusive**.

Comment: This is a United States question.

Comment: Only if some other country doesn't assert jurisdiction - that's kind of the point